# .click() on xpath element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

i´m using selenium over python and i need to execute .click() over a xpath element but when i launch the script show me an error:

i use:

```
add_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='delicious']/div[1]/aside/ul/li[5]/a")


add_link.click()
```

then show me:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 65, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 402, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
Stacktrace:
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpP85qVY/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9587)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpP85qVY/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12257)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpP85qVY/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpP85qVY/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpP85qVY/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
```

Comment: Please show the HTML representation of the page or share the link to it (if possible).

Comment: The link is https://delicious.com/tessto or another user,  i want to click on add link option but when i select with xpath launch the error

Comment: Please show the complete code you are using, also providing selenium package and browser versions.

Comment: FYI, I don't get any errors.